# Convert external image links into inline pictures?

Tags: discussion, images

Is there any function to automatically convert external image links into inline pictures? Or am I required to download them to my machine first and drag and drop them somehow onto the posting?

Comment: I make a local image and then use the image ICON in the answer post icon bar

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there any function to automatically convert external image links into inline pictures?

Click the image icon (it looks like a mountain):

[image]

From here you can "Browse, drag & drop, or paste an image or link"